# What is the actual statement of Ramsey's theorem?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I am a new to graph theory. In the 4-th lecture given by our instructor Ramsey's theorem was introduced to us. Let $[n]=\{1,2, \cdots , n \}$. He has given the statement as follows $:$

> Given positive integers $k,r,l$ ($l \geq k$), $\exists$ a positive integer $n=n(k,r,l)$ such that if the collection of $k$-subsets of $[n]$ is of $r$-coloured then $\exists$ an $l$-element subset $L$ of $[n]$ such that all the $k$-subsets of $L$ are monochromatic.

The generalized version of Ramsey's theorem is given as follows $:$

> Given positive integers $l_1,l_2, \cdots , l_r$ such that for any $r$-coloring of the $k$-subsets $\exists$ some $1 \leq i \leq  r$ such that $\exists$ an $l_i$-subset $L$ of $[n]$ such that all the $k$-subsets of $L$ are monochromatic.

But I can't find the similarity of the above theorem given by our instructor and the same given in wikipedia. What's going wrong in it?

Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The statement of the second theorem is broken. There should be universal quantifiers over $k$ and $r$ and an existential quantifier over $n$. A correct beginning would be "Given positive integers $k$, $r$ and $l_1,l_2,\ldots,l_r$, $\exists$ a positive integer $n$ such that ...".

Comment: Are they correct?

Comment: Is what correct? I just wrote that the second one is wrong.

Comment: What would be the correct version of it?

Comment: Why  it has no connection with that one given in wikipedia?

Comment: I'd provided a correct version in an edit to my comment above; perhaps you need to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: Actually there's a further mistake in the second one -- at the end, it should say "monochromatic of colour $i$". If I were you, I'd change professors if you have the chance (or copy his statements more carefully).

Comment: Actually I have said it earlier in my post that I am a new to this subject.

Comment: Can you provide me some link which proves the generalized version? That will help me a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure what being new to the subject has to do with it. You presented something as a statement from your professor; no knowledge of the subject is required to reproduce a statement.

Comment: Chapter $2$ of [these lecture notes](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schacht/lnotes/Ramsey.pdf) contains first a presentation of the general theorem, then a proof for the cases $k=1$ (pigeonhole principle) and $k=2$ (Ramsey's theorem for graphs as on Wikipedia) and then a proof for the general case.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement is a generalization of the form of the theorem given on Wikipedia, which is the special case $k=2$. In the case $k=2$, the $2$-subsets of $[n]$ correspond to the edges in the complete undirected graph on $[n]$.